# web.config to override settings.settings values of another project

Tags: .net, web-services, configuration

I have a web service application written in C# by a fellow developer. 
It consists of several projects, one of which is responsible to communicate with the DB thus contain a Settings.Settings with the connection strings and few more settings.
When compiled this project was built to a .dll so I cannot change it.

The web service application has a default Web.config file.
Now I need to change the connection string of my project and I thought, is it possible through the web configuration, can I override the default values of the settings file.

I understand my fellow didn't do an amazing job to start with, but to spare me some coding , time, can I workaround it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You require to change URL behavior from static to dynamic.

Refer below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic